# Form validation in ajax requires only the first input in the class to be filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, class, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to do validation for my form. I want to make it so if any item with class "required" is empty the form won't be submitted. Right now this is the case only for the first item in the class. For example, I have 3 inputs with class "required" - name, surname, address. The form is sent when I fill in only name, but surname and address are still empty.

Similar problem with $('.required').addClass('error'); - it should have a red border only in the empty field, but it has it on all the fields with "required" class. Is there a way to fix it?

```js
$(function() {

  $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('.required').val() === '') {
      $('#add').addClass('error');
      $('.required').addClass('error');
      $('#text').html("Fill in the form.");;
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: 'php/php.php',
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function() {
          document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "success";
          document.getElementById("add").style.border = "2px solid green";
        },
        error: function() {
          document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "error";
          document.getElementById("add").style.border = "2px solid red";
        }
      });
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">Placeholder</p>

<form id="form" method="POST" action="php/php.php">

  <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" class="required"><br>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <input type="number" name="x1" class="required">
      <input type="text" name="xa1" class="required">
      <be>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="number" name="x2">
      <input type="text" name="xa2"><br>
    </li>

    <input type="submit" name="Add" id="add">

</form>
```

Comment: the selector $(".required") return a collection of jquery dom element if you have multiple dom element with class required. you can't use .val() directly , use .each() to iterate each dom found or a loop. see jquerry doc for selector returning multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.required')` return a collection of jQuery DOM element, so you need to loop through this collection. Try this solution

```js
    $(function () {

        $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            let alllfine = true;
            $('.required').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $('#text').html("Fill in the form.");
                    $('#add').addClass('error');
                    $(this).addClass('error');
                    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
                    alllfine = false;
                } else {
                    $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
                }
            })
            if (alllfine) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: 'php/php.php',
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function () {
                        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "success";
                        document.getElementById("add").style.border = "2px solid green";
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "error";
                        document.getElementById("add").style.border = "2px solid red";
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">Placeholder</p>

<form id="form" method="POST" action="php/php.php">

    <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" class="required"><br>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <input type="number" name="x1" class="required">
            <input type="text" name="xa1" class="required">
            <be>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="number" name="x2">
            <input type="text" name="xa2"><br>
        </li>

        <input type="submit" name="Add" id="add">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test each of the fields returned

```
const $req = $('.required');
const valid = $req.filter(function() { 
  const thisValid = this.value.trim() !== "";
  $(this).toggleClass('error',!thisValid);
  return thisValid }).length === $req.length;
if (valid) {
  // ajax here
}
```

But why not just use required attribute?

```js
$(function() {

  $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
   // we will only see this if required fields are filled in
   console.log("ajax here")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">Placeholder</p>

<form id="form" method="POST" action="php/php.php">

  <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" class="required"><br>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <input type="number" name="x1" required>
      <input type="text" name="xa1" required>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="number" name="x2">
      <input type="text" name="xa2"><br>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <input type="submit" name="Add" id="add">

</form>
```

Comment: I want to have more control over the form. I can have red borders, text to fill in the form and visuals on a submit button.

Comment: See new update for a more complete script with each field set to error if empty